# Set Custom Http Header For All Outgoing Requests

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, http-headers

I'm working on a project where I need to set a custom http header from a value in localStorage on all requests.  Since my web app has to get the value from client side, I'm struggling to work out how to ensure that every Http request sent from the user contains this header.

Once the header is set in a request, it's propagated to the response using a servlet filter.  The filter checks for the header in the request and redirects to an initialization page that I can use to get the localStorage value and setup any listeners required.

```
public void doFilter( @NotNull final ServletRequest request,
                      @NotNull final ServletResponse response,
                      FilterChain filterChain ) throws IOException, ServletException {
    final HttpServletRequest hsr = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    final String value = hsr.getHeader("Custom-Header");

    if( isNullOrEmpty(value) ) {

        ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect("./init.html");

    } else {

        ((HttpServletResponse)response).setHeader("Custom-Header", value);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

    }
}
```

So on the client side, I should have the header to work with in the response, if needed.  I just can't come up with a clean, cross-browser solution to ensure that all outgoing http requests after the initial have this custom header set.

I like this observer-based solution from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Setting_HTTP_request_headers but I can't rely solely on XPCOM components that aren't supported in other browsers.